# Making For Loop over data name in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have grid data at .csv format:

```
srcPath = "/data.csv"
f = open(srcPath,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

miss  = -9999.
ny,nx = 360,720
dlat  = 0.5
dlon  = 0.5
lat0  = -90.0
lon0  = -180.0
Lat   = arange(-90, 90+0.001, dlat)
Lon   = arange(-180, 180+0.001, dlon)

a2dat0 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
a2dat1 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
a2dat3 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
a2dat4 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
a2dat5 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
a2dat6 = ones([ny,nx],float32)*miss
for line in lines:
  lon, lat, v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6 =map(float,line.split(","))
  x = int(floor((lon - lon0)/dlon))
  y = int(floor((lat - lat0)/dlat))
  a2dat0 [y,x] = v0
  a2dat1 [y,x] = v1
  a2dat2 [y,x] = v2
  a2dat3 [y,x] = v3
  a2dat4 [y,x] = v4
  a2dat5 [y,x] = v5
  a2dat6 [y,x] = v6
X, Y = meshgrid(Lon, Lat)
m= Basemap(projection='robin',llcrnrlon=-180.,llcrnrlat=-90.,urcrnrlon=180.,urcrnrlat=90.,resolution='i',lon_0=0)
xi, yi = m(X, Y)
```

Now I want to make loof over "a2dat" like:

```
  for i in range (0,7,1):
      print a2dat+str(i)+":" ,a2dat+str(i).shape
```

or

```
  for i in range (0,7,1):
      cs+str(i) = m.pcolor(xi,yi,a2dat+str(i),cmap=cmap, norm=norm, )
```

to plot 7 different global maps using basemap and "a2dat" data, but It gives the back error, So how could I make the loop over these data name?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: it is error when  I just want print "a2dat+str(i)" in for loop "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')"

Comment: Use a list 7 arrays and you won't have to fiddle in a non-python way with name generation.

Comment: If the code is already clear as written, why make it obscure with this loop and name generation? This is python, not some primitive language without lists or dictionaries.

Comment: @hpaulj sorry, but I didn't catch your point and this kind of comments never help anyone. I got my answer from others.

Comment: If the arrays are in a list, you could use then without generating the names each time.  `for dat in alist:print(dat.shape)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to dynamically interpret python code from a string you need to use `eval` or `exec`. Also your print statement is wrong because it should not have `:`, and the first `a2dat` should be a string since you just want to get the text (also note I added a `,`).

```
  for i in range (0,7):
      print "a2dat"+str(i)+":", eval("a2dat"+str(i)).shape
```

`eval("a2dat"+str(i))` will get you the array object when it's evaluated. You can read up on the difference between `eval` and `exec` on your own.

Comment: thank you, for **print** It was just my typing mistake, but `eval` yes it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think your dynamic names could be replaced with lists as follows (this isn't runnable code, so may have some bugs):

```
data = [np.ones([ny,nx], float32)*miss for _ in range(7)]
# data = [a2dat0, a2dat1, ... a2dat6]    # or a list of the arrays
for line in lines:
  lon, lat, *vs =map(float,line.split(","))    # py3 * unpacking
  # vs = alist[2:] in py2?
  x = int(floor((lon - lon0)/dlon))
  y = int(floor((lat - lat0)/dlat))
  for d,v in zip(data, vs):
       d[y,x] = v
```

(Once the arrays are collecting a list, their names, if any, in the global environment aren't important.)

and

```
for i,d  in enumerate(data):
     print("a2dat%d: "%i ,data.shape)

csdata = [m.pcolor(xi, yi, d, ...) for d in data]
```

While it is possible to use `for i in range(...):` loops, generating the index with `enumerate` is more idiomatic.  We're encouraged to think about iterating over a list of objects, not over the indices of those elements.